# How to use login_required decorator once to make it effective on every single function without hardcoding and putting it on every single function?

Tags: django

so I am building an app where I want users to login before accessing certain pages. To do that, I need to use the login_required decorator. But I find it annoying to use that decorator on every single function that renders a page to make it useful. Do you know a way, that I can use it once and make it effective on every single page or function that renders the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a middleware to force every user to login first.
[django-login-required-middleware](https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/) could be helpful.
In case you need, you can ignore some views or paths from this.

Comment: you are welcome. in addition to choosing an answer as the best one, you are able to upvote every answer including the chosen answer. thank you @Suhas

Comment: yeah, no problem! I can't vote it though. I am new to this website, and I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Hello @mahyard, I just got a notification saying that I have reached my question limit. It looks like this: file:///media/fuse/drivefs-35dccd4a17d6417c15c9078d844e9362/root/Screenshot%202021-06-10%207.59.31%20PM.png

Comment: I have a question, how come I got this when I asked good questions?

Comment: And also, will this ban ever be taken? Thanks for your help

Comment: I cannot see the image you sent. please search the error in Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Ok, thank you! But I didn't see any searches that matched the error I got!